# Fetching number of rows & column using Id in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to calculate number of rows and column of a table in selenium(Java).
I did some research and all I found was *using XPath*.

Though my code is working fine with XPath, I wanted to know that "Is it possible to achieve this using Element`Id`?"

EDITED:
[image: Table HTML]

My Code(with is working fine, but using XPath):

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[@id='ctl00_TxnContentPage_grdLoanDetails']/tbody/tr"));
            System.out.println("Row count" + rows.size());
```

Let me know if you need any specific detail.

Comment: If you have all the rows same ID and columns having same ID then you can try this approach. anyway, that will be bad idea from development perspective of a application. XPath is way better.

Comment: As per my perspective, have same IDs for all the rows/column (which gets generated at the run time dynamically) is the good practice of development. [Correct me if I am wrong]

Comment: @Abhinav 
XPath is never considered as better way to find element as it downgrades the performance of Automation Testing. It is always used as alternative.

Comment: How about adding the relevant html to your post. If it is a simple table without any colspan, rowspan etc it should be easy. Just count the number or tr tags and the td tags within a single tr tag.

Comment: @Grasshopper I have edited my post with the screenshot of HTML(sorry, I count copy-past as I was not getting any way to do it) and my Code (XPath) which is working

Comment: CSS  count for rows - table[id='ctl00_TxnContentPage_grdLoanDetails'] > tbody > tr... Subtract 1 from the list size as first row will be header or you can use table[id='ctl00_TxnContentPage_grdLoanDetails'] > tbody > tr:not([class]) which will only returns tr's without class attribute in them(Will fail if someone adds a class to trs later on).    CSS  count for columns -table[id='ctl00_TxnContentPage_grdLoanDetails'] > tbody > tr > th... Just get the size of this list...

Comment: @Grasshopper
The way you are using seems useful for me as we will not have any HTML code changes. But I am not sure how to implement the CSS you gave above. I have used XPath in my code By.xpath(".//table[@id='ctl00_TxnContentPage_grdLoanDetails'‌​]/tbody/tr")

Comment: I have just given you the CSS locators. Use it inside By.cssSelector(). Please google "selenium tutorials" or search on youtube. You will get almost all of the questions you are asking.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks, it is working for me.
Actually I was aware of CSS Locator but I thought you answer can be(somehow) implemented using `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should be more robust

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_TxnContentPage_grdLoanDetails"));
WebElement tableBody = table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
int rowCount = tableBody.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();
```

Comment: Indeed. it is robust.

Comment: This isn't any more robust than what you had. In fact, it's exactly the same (results-wise) but probably 3x slower because you are scraping the page three times instead of once.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a CSS Selector. It will be slightly faster but you'd have to test for yourself to see how much faster... we're probably talking 100ms faster or something in that range.

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_TxnContentPage_grdLoanDetails > tbody > tr"));
System.out.println("Row count" + rows.size());
```

CSS Selectors are pretty much always going to be faster than any other locator because browsers have been optimized to use it because it's so common.

This does use the ID, as you can see in `#ctl00_TxnContentPage_grdLoanDetails`, but it's not (obviously) using `By.id()`.

Comment: Thanks for this info.
As my application (Banking Domain) mainly deals in the Transaction, I need to keep performance in mind.

Comment: Hi, I have been following your work since very long. I am a QA, stated working as a Lead to develop a Hybrid Data Driven Framework for Banking application. I have coded all my tests but I know I had not put it in a Framework manner. If possible, assist me to do so. Let me know if you need any details (I had nowhere to contact you, so I commented here).

Comment: Your best bet is to read a lot of articles and try some things. See what works and improve what doesn't. If you run into a coding issue, post a question here and maybe I'll see it. You might try some of the other SE sites like programming or the testing related sites where you can ask more advice-type questions.

Comment: Thank you sir, for you reply.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now. I started documenting the details from internet and picked you what is suited for my application. By this, I end you creating what I wanted. Though, it still needs lots of improvement but I guess I am on right way.